# Issue while converting from JSON to XML

Tags: javascript, xml

When I am converting the below `JSON` to `XML`, it seems that `__text` property is being stripped off from the XML.

```
{
    "root": {
        "number": {
            "__text": "1\n-\n222\n-\n500"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell how the `__text` property changes and what `__text` represents?

Below is a fiddle and library used

http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gtLBx/15/

https://code.google.com/p/x2js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__text` property changes from the `Javascript` syntax of a multi-line string to the `XML` syntax of a multi-line string.
This means that `\n` is converted to a newline.

`1\n-\n222\n-\n500`

will then become

```
1
-
222
-
500
```

which is the same, in different notation

Without knowing the library you're using, I'd guess that `__text` represents the content of the property you're describing.

Looking into the source of the library it seems like `_` indicates an attribute and the attribute `__text` is a special attribute to indicate the text contained inside an XML element when the element also has attributes.

Here is an updated fiddle that should help you to understand this better: https://jsfiddle.net/gtLBx/924/

Here are the source code snippets, that imply the things I assumed:

1. `_` is an attribute, because of [line 31](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/source/browse/xml2json.js):

   config.attributePrefix = config.attributePrefix || "_";
2. `_text` is the name of an internal attribute, because of [this line 272](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/source/browse/xml2json.js):

   result.__text = result.__text.join("\n");

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to the code where it says _ also an attribute and just because it has _ does the __text comes into the picture?

Comment: Do you understand, what I mean now?

Comment: when the node value has 1-222-500 [hiphen, it adds _text property in json], this is my confusion

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing. `<root><number>1-222-500</number></root>` gets converted to `{"root":{"number":"1-222-500"}}`  with the fiddle you provided.

Comment: That's the strange thing happening here, when using the library specifically in IE11... is there any code which states that. https://code.google.com/p/x2js/wiki/AllAvailableConfigOptions in this what does enableToStringFunc  means? does it says __text will be removed.

Comment: Even Internet Explorer 11 doesn't add __text when converting the above example. I just tested it.

Comment: does this enableToStringFunc make any sense? for me the issue comes only in production and not in local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83128/discussion-between-dodekeract-and-freak-head).